# Rsync suddenly hanging when using recursive flag and on normal operations

Tags: linux, file, networking, rsync

I'm using rsync to sync data from a VPS to a local storage NAS connected via a Wireguard tunnel.

This has been working perfectly for months but I noticed a few weeks ago that syncs wouldn't complete anymore.

I investigated a bit and found out that rsync just starts to hang in certain operations and eventually times out because of this. Here's the log from an rsync operation using -vvvrP flags:

```
opening connection using: ssh -l tali 192.168.6.2 rsync --server -vvvre.iLsfxC --partial . /home/tali/hdd/gitea/  (10 args)
sending incremental file list
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories,*,0)
send_file_list done
[sender] pushing local filters for /var/lib/gitea/data/gitea-repositories/
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/amenia,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/tali,*,2)
send_files starting
[sender] pushing local filters for /var/lib/gitea/data/gitea-repositories/amenia/
[sender] pushing local filters for /var/lib/gitea/data/gitea-repositories/guests/
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.wiki.git,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git,*,2)
[sender] pushing local filters for /var/lib/gitea/data/gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/HEAD,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/refs,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/branches,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/config,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/objects,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/info,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/description,*,2)
[sender] pushing local filters for /var/lib/gitea/data/gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/branches/
[sender] pushing local filters for /var/lib/gitea/data/gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/post-receive,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/pre-receive.d,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/pre-receive,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/pre-push.sample,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/pre-merge-commit.sample,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/post-update.sample,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/pre-receive.sample,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/update.sample,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/guests/mystory.git/hooks/update,*,2)

...

server_recv(2) starting pid=3801
recv_file_name(gitea-repositories)
received 1 names
recv_file_list done
recv_file_name(gitea-repositories/guests)
recv_file_name(gitea-repositories/amenia)
recv_file_name(gitea-repositories/tali)
received 3 names
recv_file_list done
get_local_name count=4 /home/tali/hdd/gitea/
generator starting pid=3801
delta-transmission enabled
recv_generator(gitea-repositories,1)
recv_generator(gitea-repositories,2)
recv_generator(gitea-repositories/amenia,3)
recv_generator(gitea-repositories/guests,4)
recv_generator(gitea-repositories/tali,5)
recv_files(1) starting
[sender] pushing local filters for /var/lib/gitea/data/gitea-repositories/tali/substance-shelf.git/objects/28/
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/tali/substance-shelf.git/objects/28/f9607ed2fc8526cd1a230bf13c30c596d70f49,*,2)
[sender] pushing local filters for /var/lib/gitea/data/gitea-repositories/tali/substance-shelf.git/objects/2a/
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/tali/substance-shelf.git/objects/2a/017918a202a1cbd7fa760c98ec067887dc9f62,*,2)
[sender] pushing local filters for /var/lib/gitea/data/gitea-repositories/tali/substance-shelf.git/objects/2c/
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/tali/substance-shelf.git/objects/2c/f02ceb2ef15ba367d412fd5cfaaf6aab3cf049,*,2)
[sender] make_file(gitea-repositories/tali/substance-shelf.git/objects/2c/48da4ed78357c447e1fe33a07c61579acb3254,*,2)
send_files(2, /var/lib/gitea/data/gitea-repositories)
```

It won't progress any further than this and hangs at this step forever.
However I've found out that the operation completes successfully if I remove the -r flag. But obviously that means not all data is being transferred. (Same is true for -a which implies -r)

I've also noticed a problem when transferring a singular file that already exists in the destination but has an older modification date. Rsync would also hang in this operation unless I added the -W flag. This made that singular operation work but had no effect on transferring directories with many files and sub-directories.

I'd also like to add that this has worked flawlessly for months, I've recently moved so the destination, my local nas, is now on a different network. However I've already opened all relevant ports and verified the Wireguard tunnel works.

Edit
The local NAS is currently on a Fritz.Box router network. I'm suspecting that may be part of the issue since that is the only thing that changed, it was previously on another ISPs router in a different network

**What I've tried**

- I've tried several different flag combinations also including -t and reducing verbosity all with the same problem.
- I've verified that there's a connection to the destination NAS and that I can send testfiles through the tunnel using rsync.
- I've verified that the destination has enough available space and that the partition and filesystem is clean and healthy

Finally here's a strace log of running the operation: https://pastebin.com/uZ3U75Es

Edit:

I just verified that an rsync operation locally works flawlessly so the issue has to be somewhere in the network

Edit 2:

I ran Tshark on the destination device once with sending a single file which is known to work and once with the folder that makes rsync hang:

Working single file:

```
    1 0.000000000  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSH 1420 Server: Encrypted packet (len=1368)
    2 7.856558678  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 60 58102 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64860 Len=0 MSS=1380 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1863568490 TSecr=0 WS=128
    3 7.856686766  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 60 22 → 58102 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64296 Len=0 MSS=1380 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3686958982 TSecr=1863568490 WS=128
    4 7.903160449  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64896 Len=0 TSval=1863568536 TSecr=3686958982
    5 7.905068438  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  SSH 93 Client: Protocol (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4)
    6 7.905149316  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=42 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686959031 TSecr=1863568538
    7 7.945103709  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 93 Server: Protocol (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4)
    8 7.984842010  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=42 Ack=42 Win=64896 Len=0 TSval=1863568617 TSecr=3686959071
    9 7.984920930  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 1108 Server: Key Exchange Init
   10 7.986205854  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 196 [TCP Previous segment not captured]  [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   11 7.986251647  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 64 [TCP Dup ACK 6#1] 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=1098 Ack=42 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686959112 TSecr=1863568617 SLE=1410 SRE=1554
   12 7.986585076  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 1420 [TCP Out-Of-Order] 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=42 Ack=42 Win=64896 Len=1368 TSval=1863568619 TSecr=3686959071
   13 7.986640870  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=1098 Ack=1554 Win=63872 Len=0 TSval=3686959112 TSecr=1863568619
   14 8.024536268  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=1554 Ack=1098 Win=63872 Len=0 TSval=1863568658 TSecr=3686959110
   15 8.029828260  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 100 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1554 Ack=1098 Win=64256 Len=48 TSval=1863568663 TSecr=3686959112 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   16 8.029874887  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=1098 Ack=1602 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686959155 TSecr=1863568663
   17 8.056590318  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 560 Server: Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Reply, New Keys, Encrypted packet (len=228)
   18 8.096297659  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=1602 Ack=1606 Win=63872 Len=0 TSval=1863568730 TSecr=3686959182
   19 8.100514403  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 68 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1602 Ack=1606 Win=64256 Len=16 TSval=1863568734 TSecr=3686959182 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   20 8.100569322  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=1606 Ack=1618 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686959226 TSecr=1863568734
   21 8.142021396  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 96 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1618 Ack=1606 Win=64256 Len=44 TSval=1863568774 TSecr=3686959226 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   22 8.142061064  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=1606 Ack=1662 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686959268 TSecr=1863568774
   23 8.142215528  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 96 Server: Encrypted packet (len=44)
   24 8.183294588  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 112 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1662 Ack=1650 Win=64256 Len=60 TSval=1863568816 TSecr=3686959268 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   25 8.183337506  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=1650 Ack=1722 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686959309 TSecr=1863568816
   26 8.190426234  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 104 Server: Encrypted packet (len=52)
   27 8.232761883  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 552 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1722 Ack=1702 Win=64256 Len=500 TSval=1863568865 TSecr=3686959316 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   28 8.236371687  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 512 Server: Encrypted packet (len=460)
   29 8.290320194  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 960 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2222 Ack=2162 Win=64256 Len=908 TSval=1863568923 TSecr=3686959362 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   30 8.298459878  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 80 Server: Encrypted packet (len=28)
   31 8.339603816  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 164 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3130 Ack=2190 Win=64256 Len=112 TSval=1863568972 TSecr=3686959424 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   32 8.380010183  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=2190 Ack=3242 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686959506 TSecr=1863568972
   33 8.861940693  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 828 Server: Encrypted packet (len=776)
   34 8.946259312  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3242 Ack=2966 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863569580 TSecr=3686959987
   35 8.946333565  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 244 Server: Encrypted packet (len=192)
   36 8.986735890  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3242 Ack=3158 Win=64128 Len=0 TSval=1863569620 TSecr=3686960072
   37 8.987760137  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 288 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3242 Ack=3158 Win=64256 Len=236 TSval=1863569620 TSecr=3686960072 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   38 8.987829973  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=3158 Ack=3478 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686960113 TSecr=1863569620
   39 8.989991388  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 124 Server: Encrypted packet (len=72)
   40 9.017629020  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 96 Server: Encrypted packet (len=44)
   41 9.031416127  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3478 Ack=3230 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863569664 TSecr=3686960116
   42 9.031416335  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 96 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3478 Ack=3230 Win=64256 Len=44 TSval=1863569664 TSecr=3686960116 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   43 9.031481421  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=3274 Ack=3522 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686960157 TSecr=1863569664
   44 9.031671428  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 96 Server: Encrypted packet (len=44)
   45 9.058854543  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3522 Ack=3274 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863569692 TSecr=3686960143
   46 9.074682394  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3522 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863569708 TSecr=3686960157
   47 9.075753935  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 120 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3522 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=68 TSval=1863569708 TSecr=3686960157 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   48 9.075798186  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=3318 Ack=3590 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686960201 TSecr=1863569708
   49 9.077237324  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 144 Server: Encrypted packet (len=92)
   50 9.118715148  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 136 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3590 Ack=3410 Win=64256 Len=84 TSval=1863569752 TSecr=3686960203 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   51 9.119739104  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 96 Server: Encrypted packet (len=44)
   52 9.163748232  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 96 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3674 Ack=3454 Win=64256 Len=44 TSval=1863569797 TSecr=3686960245 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   53 9.164198791  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 96 Server: Encrypted packet (len=44)
   54 9.205239848  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 104 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3718 Ack=3498 Win=64256 Len=52 TSval=1863569838 TSecr=3686960290 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   55 9.205615738  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 96 Server: Encrypted packet (len=44)
   56 9.210508007  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 228 Server: Encrypted packet (len=176)
   57 9.249451401  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3770 Ack=3718 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863569882 TSecr=3686960331
   58 9.249451735  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 88 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3770 Ack=3718 Win=64256 Len=36 TSval=1863569882 TSecr=3686960331 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   59 9.249540905  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 112 58102 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3806 Ack=3718 Win=64256 Len=60 TSval=1863569882 TSecr=3686960331 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   60 9.249541155  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [FIN, ACK] Seq=3866 Ack=3718 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863569882 TSecr=3686960331
   61 9.249671993  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [ACK] Seq=3718 Ack=3867 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686960375 TSecr=1863569882
   62 9.260646409  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58102 [FIN, ACK] Seq=3718 Ack=3867 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686960386 TSecr=1863569882
   63 9.303311695  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58102 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3867 Ack=3719 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863569936 TSecr=3686960386
```

Not working folder:

```
    1 0.000000000  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 60 58100 → 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64860 Len=0 MSS=1380 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1863492218 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2 0.000123672  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 60 22 → 58100 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64296 Len=0 MSS=1380 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3686882712 TSecr=1863492218 WS=128
    3 0.039793606  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64896 Len=0 TSval=1863492258 TSecr=3686882712
    4 0.040977028  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  SSH 93 Client: Protocol (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4)
    5 0.041062115  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=42 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686882753 TSecr=1863492259
    6 0.080631587  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 93 Server: Protocol (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4)
    7 0.119967549  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=42 Ack=42 Win=64896 Len=0 TSval=1863492338 TSecr=3686882792
    8 0.120049219  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 1108 Server: Key Exchange Init
    9 0.120094970  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 196 [TCP Previous segment not captured]  [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   10 0.120129513  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 64 [TCP Dup ACK 5#1] 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=1098 Ack=42 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686882832 TSecr=1863492338 SLE=1410 SRE=1554
   11 0.121283310  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 1420 [TCP Out-Of-Order] 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=42 Ack=42 Win=64896 Len=1368 TSval=1863492339 TSecr=3686882792
   12 0.121334479  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=1098 Ack=1554 Win=63872 Len=0 TSval=3686882833 TSecr=1863492339
   13 0.160503976  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=1554 Ack=1098 Win=63872 Len=0 TSval=1863492379 TSecr=3686882832
   14 0.164865443  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 100 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1554 Ack=1098 Win=64256 Len=48 TSval=1863492383 TSecr=3686882833 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   15 0.164923404  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=1098 Ack=1602 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686882877 TSecr=1863492383
   16 0.191781654  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 560 Server: Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Reply, New Keys, Encrypted packet (len=228)
   17 0.231492465  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=1602 Ack=1606 Win=63872 Len=0 TSval=1863492449 TSecr=3686882903
   18 0.235708385  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 68 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1602 Ack=1606 Win=64256 Len=16 TSval=1863492454 TSecr=3686882903 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   19 0.235742220  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=1606 Ack=1618 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686882947 TSecr=1863492454
   20 0.274193188  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 96 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1618 Ack=1606 Win=64256 Len=44 TSval=1863492492 TSecr=3686882947 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   21 0.274217564  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=1606 Ack=1662 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686882986 TSecr=1863492492
   22 0.274287691  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 96 Server: Encrypted packet (len=44)
   23 0.318821030  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 112 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1662 Ack=1650 Win=64256 Len=60 TSval=1863492536 TSecr=3686882986 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   24 0.318863198  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=1650 Ack=1722 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686883031 TSecr=1863492536
   25 0.326655929  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 104 Server: Encrypted packet (len=52)
   26 0.365384242  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 552 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1722 Ack=1702 Win=64256 Len=500 TSval=1863492583 TSecr=3686883038 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   27 0.369000096  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 512 Server: Encrypted packet (len=460)
   28 0.416936361  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 960 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2222 Ack=2162 Win=64256 Len=908 TSval=1863492635 TSecr=3686883081 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   29 0.425705298  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 80 Server: Encrypted packet (len=28)
   30 0.465353063  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 164 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3130 Ack=2190 Win=64256 Len=112 TSval=1863492683 TSecr=3686883137 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   31 0.505869530  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=2190 Ack=3242 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686883218 TSecr=1863492683
   32 0.985216811  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 828 Server: Encrypted packet (len=776)
   33 1.069340702  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3242 Ack=2966 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863493288 TSecr=3686883697
   34 1.069419246  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 244 Server: Encrypted packet (len=192)
   35 1.109461777  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3242 Ack=3158 Win=64128 Len=0 TSval=1863493328 TSecr=3686883781
   36 1.109462194  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 288 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3242 Ack=3158 Win=64256 Len=236 TSval=1863493328 TSecr=3686883781 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   37 1.109554364  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3158 Ack=3478 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686883821 TSecr=1863493328
   38 1.111783037  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 124 Server: Encrypted packet (len=72)
   39 1.138853212  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 96 Server: Encrypted packet (len=44)
   40 1.152583432  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3478 Ack=3230 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863493371 TSecr=3686883823
   41 1.152639268  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 96 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3478 Ack=3230 Win=64256 Len=44 TSval=1863493371 TSecr=3686883823 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   42 1.152668561  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3274 Ack=3522 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686883864 TSecr=1863493371
   43 1.152866694  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 96 Server: Encrypted packet (len=44)
   44 1.182272587  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3522 Ack=3274 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863493400 TSecr=3686883851
   45 1.201527530  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3522 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863493420 TSecr=3686883865
   46 1.209015082  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 1420 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=3522 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=1863493426 TSecr=3686883865 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   47 1.209055292  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3318 Ack=4890 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686883921 TSecr=1863493426
   48 1.209092377  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 1420 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=4890 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=1863493426 TSecr=3686883865 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   49 1.209092752  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 1420 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=6258 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=1863493426 TSecr=3686883865 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   50 1.209138962  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3318 Ack=6258 Win=63488 Len=0 TSval=3686883921 TSecr=1863493426
   51 1.209165171  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3318 Ack=7626 Win=62592 Len=0 TSval=3686883921 TSecr=1863493426
   52 1.209225840  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 1420 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=7626 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=1863493426 TSecr=3686883865 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   53 1.209226174  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 2788 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=8994 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=2736 TSval=1863493426 TSecr=3686883865 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   54 1.209226299  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 2788 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=11730 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=2736 TSval=1863493426 TSecr=3686883865 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   55 1.209226424  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 1420 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=14466 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=1863493426 TSecr=3686883865 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   56 1.209274926  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3318 Ack=8994 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686883921 TSecr=1863493426
   57 1.209307010  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3318 Ack=11730 Win=62592 Len=0 TSval=3686883921 TSecr=1863493426
   58 1.209336720  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3318 Ack=14466 Win=60672 Len=0 TSval=3686883921 TSecr=1863493426
   59 1.209380722  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 1420 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=15834 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=1863493426 TSecr=3686883865 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   60 1.209382472  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3318 Ack=15834 Win=63360 Len=0 TSval=3686883921 TSecr=1863493426
   61 1.209426557  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3318 Ack=17202 Win=62080 Len=0 TSval=3686883921 TSecr=1863493426
   62 1.250127906  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 1352 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=17202 Ack=3318 Win=64256 Len=1300 TSval=1863493468 TSecr=3686883921 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   63 1.250166449  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3318 Ack=18502 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686883962 TSecr=1863493468
   64 1.261580867  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 120 Server: Encrypted packet (len=68)
   65 1.262550031  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 2788 Server: Encrypted packet (len=2736)
   66 1.262637785  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 2788 Server: Encrypted packet (len=2736)
   67 1.263747621  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 2788 Server: Encrypted packet (len=2736)
   68 1.263776914  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 2788 Server: Encrypted packet (len=2736)
   69 1.264882834  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 1420 Server: Encrypted packet (len=1368)
   70 1.341487255  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58100 → 22 [ACK] Seq=18502 Ack=3386 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863493560 TSecr=3686883973
   71 1.341531465  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 2788 Server: Encrypted packet (len=2736)
   72 1.449850329  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  SSHv2 1420 Server: Encrypted packet (len=1368)
   73 1.705850931  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 1420 [TCP Retransmission] 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3386 Ack=18502 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=3686884418 TSecr=1863493560
   74 2.237845899  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 1420 [TCP Retransmission] 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3386 Ack=18502 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=3686884950 TSecr=1863493560
   75 3.261864485  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 1420 [TCP Retransmission] 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3386 Ack=18502 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=3686885974 TSecr=1863493560
   76 5.309870631  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 1420 [TCP Retransmission] 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3386 Ack=18502 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=3686888022 TSecr=1863493560
   77 9.533857473  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 1420 [TCP Retransmission] 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3386 Ack=18502 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=3686892246 TSecr=1863493560
   78 17.725881998  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 1420 [TCP Retransmission] 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3386 Ack=18502 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=3686900438 TSecr=1863493560
   79 34.109881458  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 1420 [TCP Retransmission] 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=3386 Ack=18502 Win=64256 Len=1368 TSval=3686916822 TSecr=1863493560
   80 50.675597084  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 112 58100 → 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=18502 Ack=3386 Win=64256 Len=60 TSval=1863542893 TSecr=3686883973 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   81 50.675597418  192.168.6.1 → 192.168.6.2  TCP 52 58100 → 22 [FIN, ACK] Seq=18562 Ack=3386 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1863542894 TSecr=3686883973
   82 50.717875054  192.168.6.2 → 192.168.6.1  TCP 52 22 → 58100 [ACK] Seq=19802 Ack=18563 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=3686933430 TSecr=1863542893
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, Tshark gave me a hint with the TCP Retransmission errors, reverse searching that on google reveals that MTU settings might be at fault and indeed that was the issue, setting the MTU correctly in Wireguard has resolved this issue